# a touchable polygon on a view ?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I need to show a view on which I need to animate a polygon using its vertices. The polygon should be touchable, thus fire an event once touched, and I need to be able to move its vertices using some animation procedure, once it has fired that event.
I need to have three polygons like that to form a 3D Cube.

The darkened area is the view (actually an image) on which I have the cube.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps in the process: drawing and event handling.

Drawing can be done with Quartz2D, by implementing a drawRect in a view, calculating the coordinates of the cube on screen, followed by creating and drawing the path, which works fine for solidly filled shapes. The alternative method uses an OpenGL view where you specify triangles.

At the event handling end, you can implement onTouchesBegan: and friends to get the location of the interaction, and possibly hitTest: to allow other views below it to handle subsequent events. The next thing you will need to decide is how accurate you want to be - you can define a box that roughly matches the cube and test that for touches. Most people will want to touch it somewhere in the middle anyway. For accurate testing, you need the screen coordinates, and test each triangle in each polygon to see if it contains the location. Google turned up [a nice explanation](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html) on the maths needed for that. In the OpenGL case, you'll have to manually repeat the calculations performed by OpenGL to find out where on screen your polygons have ended up.